# What should we do about the guess the password chess puzzles?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, vote-to-close

There have been a few of these posted lately. I have been down-voting and casting a vote to close. It's been pointed out that as puzzles, they are technically on topic, however, they aren't very useful. Should they be closed with a custom reason, or left open?

Comment: "Questions that have to do primarily with chess in its standard form are on-topic here. This includes questions about ... specific positions/games (including puzzles)..." ([source](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Herb, you beat me to it. I had the same question though I confess I had missed the nuance regarding the password angle.

Answer (score 4):

**Leave**

Upvote if you think they should be allowed to stand

Answer (score 1):

**Close**

Upvote if you think they should be closed